# Is difference between light_verify and verify just DAG size?

Tags: mining, verify

I am looking at this doc:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/blob/master/Dagger-Hashimoto.md

And from what I gather, light_verify uses quick_hashimoto which calculates the DAG using a recursive algorithm and caching all the values along the way. Is quick_hashimoto considered "light" because you just have to calculate at most `m + (mix % 2**64) % m` nodes (minimum `m` nodes) vs having to generate the whole DAG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a little digging myself and I think I understand it now. Essentially, it's known as "quick" because instead of generating the entire daggerset, we only need to calculate the node referenced in `quick_calc` part of the equation:

`mix ^= quick_calc(params, seed, m + (mix % 2**64) % m)`

quick_calc will attempt to calculate the daggerset node referenced in `daggerset[m + (mix % 2**64) % m]` of the non quick algorithm.

And to calculate this node, you only need to calculate and cache a subset of the daggerset.

This node is used for the XOR part of the dagger-hashimoto algo

`for _ in range(params["accesses"]):
    mix ^= quick_calc(params, seed, m + (mix % 2**64) % m)
    return dbl_sha3(mix)`